# Require a Vue filter with Laravel webpack

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-filter

I'm using Vue 2 with Laravel 5.4 and webpack. I load my components globally by requiring the .vue file associated:

```
Vue.component('tabs', require('./components/global/Tabs.vue'));
```

On the .vue file I have a script tag with export default {...} and everything works fine. Now I want to load a filter with the same require, but I'm not be able to do in any form. The filter is:

```
Vue.filter('formatbytes', function (bytes, decimals) {

if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
var k = 1000,
    dm = decimals + 1 || 3,
    sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];

});
```

The above works fine but, how can I put the filter logic on a separate .vue file? I have tested with the following with no luck:

```
export default {
filters: {
    formatbytes: function (bytes, decimals) {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Another:

```
export default {
formatbytes: function (bytes, decimals) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export functions as well as objects using `export default` and you don't need to have it in a `.vue` component

Try changing your code to:

```
export default function (bytes, decimals) {
    if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
    var k = 1000,
    dm = decimals + 1 || 3,
    sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));

    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

and your require should work

```
vue.filter('formatbytes', require('/path/to/filter/formatbytes.js'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error [Vue warn]: Error in render function

Comment: @IkerVázquez What does your render function look like on your root object?